# Forbidden: ecs-task to apigateway websocket connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm trying to make a `post_to_connection` request from an `ecs-task` to an `APIGateway Websocket @connection api` but was unable to do so from this `ecs-task` getting a Forbidden response every time.

This `ecs-task` has a role attached to it with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "execute-api:ManageConnections",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:*:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Tests I've done:

I have copied the credentials found on this container; `access_key_id`, `secret_access_key` and the `session` and made the requests from my local machine which was successful.

I have created a `credential object` and passed that to the `apigateway` client and made the request from inside the container but it failed again with a `Forbidden` response.

To make these requests I'm using the same version of `aws-sdk-apigatewaymanagementapi` gem.

```
client = Aws::ApiGatewayManagementApi::Client.new(endpoint: url, region: 'eu-west-1')
resp = client.post_to_connection({data: "{type: 'hello'}",connection_id: "conn_id"})
```

At this point, I'm out of ideas as I don't have too much exp with AWS. Can you think of anything I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by creating a `Custom Domain` which was pointed to this ApiGateway instance.